# How to convert list of lists from a dictionary of dictionaries into a data frame?

Tags: list, dataframe, numpy, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary of dictionaries which contains list of tuples as follows:

```
     mydict:{'Id1':{'sample1': [[1,1,5],[1,2,6],[1,3,21],[2,1,0],[2,2,0]...(10,3,54)],
              'sample2': [[1,1,21],[1,2,1],[1,3,4],[,1,23],[2,2,43]...[10,3,]],
               ...
              'sample199': [[1,1,0],[1,2,13],[1,3,32],[2,1,0],[2,2,15]...[...]],
              'sample200': [[1,1,43],[1,2,30],[1,3,6],[2,1,0],[2,2,4]...[10,3,87]]}
        'Id2':{'sample1': [[1,1,0],[1,2,0],[1,3,2],[2,1,0],[2,2,32]...[10,3,43]],
              'sample2': [[1,1,0],[1,2,15],[1,3,43],[2,1,2],[2,2,12]...[10,3,7]],
               ...
              'sample199': [[1,1,0],[1,2,3],[1,3,16],[2,1,17],[2,2,11]...[]]}
               ...
 }
```

I want to convert the above dictionary into a data frame, where the third items of the lists become the columns in the data frame (basically the number of features in the data-frame should be equal to the numbers of lists in the current dictionary). My desired outcome should be like this:

```
    mydata_frame:
                 IDs   Samples      f1      f2      f3  ...  fn
                 Id1   sample1      5       6       21  ...  53
                 Id1   sample2      21      1       4   ...  21
                 ...     ...        ..      ..      ..  ... ...
                 Id1   Sample200    43      30      6   ...  87
                 Id2   sample1      0       0       2   ...  43
                 Id2   sample2      0       15      43  ...  7
                 ...   ...           ...
```

I tried the below code, but it did not work:

```
    mydata_frame= [[key] + i for key,value in mydict.items() for i in value]
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible dictionary that can be used for the problem you have mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not straight forward using below, melting a dataframe is a way of representing column values as rows.

Melt columns so that id and samples will be rows. Then split values/features into dataframe using apply

```py
mydict = {'Id1':{'sample1': [(1,1,5),(1,2,6),(1,3,21),(2,1,0),(2,2,0)],
              'sample2': [(1,1,21),(1,2,1),(1,3,4),(2,1,23),(2,2,43)],
              'sample199': [(1,1,0),(1,2,13),(1,3,32),(2,1,0),(2,2,15)],
              'sample200': [(1,1,43),(1,2,30),(1,3,6),(2,1,0),(2,2,4)]},
        'Id2':{'sample1': [(1,1,0),(1,2,0),(1,3,2),(2,1,0),(2,2,32)],
              'sample2': [(1,1,0),(1,2,15),(1,3,43),(2,1,2),(2,2,12)],
              'sample199': [(1,1,0),(1,2,3),(1,3,16),(2,1,17),(2,2,11)]}}
# COnvert dict to dataframe
# it will have column IDs, index samples
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
# Make index samples as columns
df = df.reset_index()
# Convert the column names as rows
df = df.melt(id_vars=['index'])
df = df.dropna()
# This will move all values and columns as rows
# Take all the value columns, extract last element of tuple
# Generally apply will give series, but if you expand a list, it will give dataframe
df[[f'f{i}'for i in range(5)]] = df.apply(lambda x: [t[-1] for t in x['value']], axis=1, result_type='expand')
df.drop(['value'], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: When I run `df.apply(lambda x: [t[-1] for t in x['value']], axis=1, result_type='expand')
df.drop(['value'], axis=1)`´ I face the following error:  `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

Comment: I added dictionary  above. If you use different one share that. Give a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Maybe length of values for all is not same, in that case just add empty values in apply at the end inside lambda